# Android views never becoming invisible

Tags: android, xml, view

I'm trying to make some of my views invisibe. Here's the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
            android:text="See More Like This"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recommender"
            tools:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" android:layout_marginRight="24dp" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="https://www.google.com"
            android:layout_width="169dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/urlDisplay"
            tools:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp" android:layout_marginTop="101dp" android:layout_marginStart="24dp"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:id="@+id/comicTitle" tools:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp" android:layout_marginBottom="21dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/urlDisplay" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp" android:layout_marginEnd="40dp" android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

There is no kotlin code except for the boilerplate. When I start up the app, all of my views are visible. I don't understand how this is happening, given that I've explicitly set them to be invisible in xml.

How can I make them invisible?

Comment: why is it `tools:visibility` instead of `android:visibility`?

Comment: Read about [**tools**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes) prefix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [**`Tools attributes reference`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html)

> Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools
>   namespace that enable design-time features (such as which layout to
>   show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking
>   mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the
>   build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK
>   size or runtime behavior.

You should use **`android:visibility="invisible"`** instead of `tools:visibility="invisible"`

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `tools`

```
tools:visibility="invisible"
```

Just replace the `tools` with the `android` it start working fine

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used `tools:visibility="invisible"`
use `android:visibility="invisible"` to make your view invisible.

Answer (score 1):

In your xml you have set the `tools:visibility="invisible"` This is basically tools namespace supported in Android Studio
Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools namespace that enable design-time features.

When you build your app, the build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK size or run-time behavior. Hence when you run the app there is no effect of these attributes.

You can read more about tools attributes in [official android dev docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes)

As suggested in comments you should instead set `android:visibility="invisible"`